# Где в приложении хранить данные подключения к устройствам в Android приложении

Tags: android, безопасность

Не ругайте сильно новичка...
Для подключения к камере из приложения нужно обратиться к определенному адресу, например:

```
rtsp://user:password@mycameraaddres/Channels/1
```

Если эту строку хранить в переменной, то при открытии apk можно достать данные подключения "user:password", что не есть хорошо.

Вопрос: где или как хранить данные о подключении, чтобы их невозможно было вытащить из приложения?

Comment: В приложении — нигде и никак, в любом случае вытащат. Данные, которые вы не хотите раскрывать, в принципе не должны попадать на устройства, которым вы не доверяете. Если вы хотите передать в приложение видеопоток со своей камеры — значит запускайте свой собственный прокси-сервер, который будет подключаться к камере с паролем и передавать его в приложение уже без пароля (или с другим паролем, который вам не жалко опубликовать).

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Ваш комментарий натолкнул меня на мысль: подключение телефона все равно проходит авторизацию. Просто сделал класс, который будет подключаться к серверу с токеном и отдавать строку подключения к камере только после прохождения авторизации и из приложения её убрал.